# PHP Login/Logout Issues

Tags: php

I have been picking up some PHP to get into Wordpress development and I was trying to build a login/logout system but there are a few problems,

So I've got **index.php**

```
    <?php
ini_set("session.save_path", "/home/system/sessionData");
    session_start();
   
        
include('functions.php')  
 ?> 


         <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in']) : ?>
   <p>   please login</p>
       
      
            <form method="post" action="login.php">
                        Username <input type="text" name="username">
                        Password <input type="password" name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Logon">
                </form>
               
                <?php endif; ?>
            
        </div>


       
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in'] == true) : ?>
           just logged in content
           <a href="logout.php" class="logout-link">Logout</a> 
           <?php endif; ?>
```

Then I've got login.php which is just basically getting data and validating it from a DB which is all working fine but when I logout and redirect my user back to index.php, I am not able to see any of the div's on index.php just a blank white page.

my logout.php

```
ini_set("session.save_path", "/home/system/sessionData");   
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['logged-in']);
session_destroy();
header('Location:index.php');
die;
```

If I add the following "  $_SESSION['logged-in'] = ''; " at the top of my index.php, I'm able to see the content but the session is not saving obviously, I believe the whole problem has something to do with this? I have defined this session in my login.php should I define it again in index.php?

Comment: try debug by enable error in your code, add error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: One thing that I've noticed after playing around with the code a bit is if I put this $_SESSION['logged-in'] = '''; at the top of my index.php I'm able to see the content but it is however not saving sessions as even after logging in I still see the login form

Comment: are your session.save_path  ( /home/system/sessionData ) is exist and writeable ? , or you can try disable session.save_path

Comment: Yeah they exist and they are writeable, I just rechecked.

Comment: check your session status wth var_dump(session_status()); , put after session_start() and at bottom page.

Comment: it returns int(2), I'm sorry I'm not sure what that means? Do you mind explaining a bit I'm sorry I'm a beginner at PHP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226633/discussion-between-freakz0r-and-lexa-vey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem with conditional statements
in index.php

first condition for show login form is

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in']) : ?>
```

mean if `$_SESSION['logged-in']` is set and `$_SESSION['logged-in']` is set with boolean `true` will show login from.

according from your problem explanation, you must use correct condition

```
<?php  if (!isset($_SESSION['logged-in'])) : ?>
```

which mean if `$_SESSION['logged-in']` not set will show login form.